# HTML5 FileSystem requestQuota Reservation?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-filesystem

When requesting (and being granted) an increase in the quota for the FileSystem API, is that much space now reserved to Chrome and lost to other applications on the device, or is it an opportunistic quota grab, in that it will take space up to the quota, but no more than it needs at any one time?  As an example:

```
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota( 1024 * 1024 * 5000,
      function(grantedSize) {
        window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, grantedSize, function(fs) {
           filesystem = fs;
      }, fileSystemErrorHandler);
   }, fileSystemErrorHandler);
```

Through the code above is Chrome going to assign 5GB to `filesystem` no matter how it's filled, holding onto 5GB until it's cleared by the user?  Or will Chrome only take what it needs up to 5 GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome will only take what it needs up to 5 GB.